# Global variable doesn't update across threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm embarrassed to even ask this question because I thought the results of my experiment would be super obvious.

I intended to demonstrate the potential pitfalls of updating a global variable across threads. I expected the value to increase (even if it was only by 1).

But the results are that it doesn't seem to be updated at all, what am I missing about how data is shared across threads?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int global = 0;

void child_code(int i)
{
  sleep(i);
  global++;
  printf("Child %d: global=%p/%d\n", i, &global, global);
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int i, num_children;

    num_children = 10;

    for (i=0; i<num_children; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) exit(1);

        /* see if we're the parent or the child */
        if (pid == 0) {
            child_code(i);
            exit(i);
        }
    }

    /* parent continues */
    for (i=0; i<num_children; i++) {
      pid = wait(NULL);
    }

    printf("Parent: global=%p/%d\n", &global, global);

    exit(0);
}
```

Here is a sample output:

```
Child 1: global=0x10a5d7038/1
Child 2: global=0x10a5d7038/1
Child 3: global=0x10a5d7038/1
Child 4: global=0x10a5d7038/1
Child 5: global=0x10a5d7038/1
Child 6: global=0x10a5d7038/1
Child 7: global=0x10a5d7038/1
Child 8: global=0x10a5d7038/1
Child 9: global=0x10a5d7038/1
Parent: global=0x10a5d7038/0
```

Comment: pthreads? `fork` isn't using pthreads. You need to use `pthread_xxx` functions not the unix fork ones (and that's portable on windows too)

Comment: You are creating all children from one parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fork()` doesn't create threads it creates separate processes with separate memory segments. More accurately, on Linux, it clones the current process and marks all data segment pages as copy-on-write, that's why once a child process attempts to write to the variable it gets its own copy of this variable along with its own copy of the memory page where it resides.

Comment: Sigh, I _should_ be embarrassed. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Need to use pthread_create.

Comment: "More accurately it clones the current process and marks all data …" - this is far beyond what any standard specifies. Don't jump wildly between abstraction layers unnecessarily, mixing language/standard and **one possible** implementation. Expecially for a beginner this will be just confusing.